# ¿Se pueden enviar parámetros de un javascript a una clase controlador?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo dos archivos, un javascript y otra clase que funciona como controlador. Estoy usando c#, asp.net mvc y quiero saber si puedo enviar dos parámetros al controlador por medio del javascript de la vista, al llamar la función "update".

El programa consiste en hacer pagos con Paypal, pero la vista es de un monedero, el cual se puede recargar y crear a partir de Paypal.

**Este es el código de la vista:**

```
@using WebApp.Helpers;

<script src="~/Scripts/Views/vMonedero.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="card border-secondary" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="row pull-right">
            <div class="col-md-8">Monedero</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.CtrlButton(viewName: "vMonedero", id: "btnCreate", label: "Crear", onClickFunction: "Create", buttonType: "success")
                @Html.CtrlButton(viewName: "vMonedero", id: "btnUpdate", label: "Recargar", onClickFunction: "Update", buttonType: "info")

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="bs-component">
                    <form id="frmEdition">
                        @Html.CtrlInput(id: "txtIdUsuario", type: "text", label: "N° de identificación", columnDataName: "IdUsuario")
                        @Html.CtrlInput(id: "txtIdMonedero", type: "text", label: "N° de monedero", columnDataName: "IdMonedero")
                        @Html.CtrlInput(id: "txtIdMonto", type: "text", label: "Monto", columnDataName: "Monto")
                        @* @Html.CtrlDropDown(id: "drpGender", label: "Gender", listId: "LST_GENERO")*@
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@*<script>
    $('#price').click(function () {
        var monederoData = {};
        ctrlActions = new ControlActions();
        ctrlActions.GetDataForm('frmEdition');
        monederoData["Monto"] = price;
        return price;
    });
```

**Este es el código del javascript de la vista:**

```
function vMonedero() {

    //this.tblMonederoId = 'tblMonedero';
    this.service = 'monedero';
    this.ctrlActions = new ControlActions();
    this.columns = "IdUsuario, IdMonedero, Monto";
    this.paypal = new PaymentWithPayPal();

    this.RetrieveAll = function () {
        this.ctrlActions.FillTable(this.service, this.tblMonedero, false);
    }


    this.Create = function () {
        var monederoData = {};
        monederoData = this.ctrlActions.GetDataForm('frmEdition');
        if (monederoData["Monto"] == "") {
            this.ctrlActions.ShowMessage('E', "Favor ingresar el nuevo valor");
        }
        else if (isNaN(monederoData["Monto"])) {
            this.ctrlActions.ShowMessage('E', "Favor ingresar un valor numérico");
        }
        else {
            this.ctrlActions.PostToAPI(this.service, monederoData);

        }
    }

    this.Update = function () {

        var monederoData = {};
        monederoData = this.ctrlActions.GetDataForm('frmEdition');
        //Hace el post al create
        this.ctrlActions.PutToAPI(this.service, monederoData);
        //Refresca la tabla

    }
    this.Delete = function () {

        var monederoData = {};
        monederoData = this.ctrlActions.GetDataForm('frmEdition');
        //Hace el post al create
        this.ctrlActions.DeleteToAPI(this.service, monederoData);
        //Refresca la tabla

    }

    this.BindFields = function (data) {
        this.ctrlActions.BindFields('frmEdition', data);
    }
}

//ON DOCUMENT READY
$(document).ready(function () {

    var vmonedero = new vMonedero();
    //vmonedero.RetrieveAll();

});






    </script>*@
```

**Este es el código del controlador:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PaymentPayPal.Models;
using PayPal.Api;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    public class PayPalController : Controller
    {
        // GET: PayPal
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult PaymentWithPaypal(string price, string product)
        {
            //getting the apiContext as earlier
            APIContext apiContext = ConfigurationPayPal.GetAPIContext();

            try
            {
                string payerId = Request.Params["PayerID"];

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payerId))
                {

                    string baseURI = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority +
                                "/Paypal/PaymentWithPayPal?";

                    var guid = Convert.ToString((new Random()).Next(100000));

                    var createdPayment = this.CreatePayment(apiContext, baseURI + "guid=" + guid, price, product);

                    var links = createdPayment.links.GetEnumerator();

                    string paypalRedirectUrl = null;

                    while (links.MoveNext())
                    {
                        Links lnk = links.Current;

                        if (lnk.rel.ToLower().Trim().Equals("approval_url"))
                        {
                            paypalRedirectUrl = lnk.href;
                        }
                    }
                    Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id);
                    Console.WriteLine(createdPayment.id);
                    return Redirect(paypalRedirectUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    var guid = Request.Params["guid"];
                    Console.WriteLine("Session:" + Session[guid] as string);
                    var executedPayment = ExecutePayment(apiContext, payerId, Session[guid] as string);

                    if (executedPayment.state.ToLower() != "approved")
                    {
                        return View("FailureView");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                return View("FailureView");
            }

            return View("SuccessView");
        }

        private PayPal.Api.Payment payment;

        private Payment ExecutePayment(APIContext apiContext, string payerId, string paymentId)
        {
            var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution() { payer_id = payerId };
            this.payment = new Payment() { id = paymentId };
            return this.payment.Execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);
        }

        private Payment CreatePayment(APIContext apiContext, string redirectUrl, string price, string product)
        {

            var itemList = new ItemList() { items = new List<Item>() };

            itemList.items.Add(new Item()
            {
                name = product,
                currency = "USD",
                price = price,
                quantity = "1",
                sku = "sku"
            });

            var payer = new Payer() { payment_method = "paypal" };

            var redirUrls = new RedirectUrls()
            {
                cancel_url = redirectUrl,
                return_url = redirectUrl
            };

            // similar as we did for credit card, do here and create details object
            var details = new Details()
            {
                tax = "1",
                shipping = "1",
                subtotal = price
            };

            // similar as we did for credit card, do here and create amount object
            var amount = new Amount()
            {
                currency = "USD",
                total = "" + (int.Parse(price) + 1 + 1), // Total must be equal to sum of shipping, tax and subtotal.
                details = details
            };

            var transactionList = new List<Transaction>();

            transactionList.Add(new Transaction()
            {
                description = "Transaction description.",
                invoice_number = Convert.ToString((new Random()).Next(100000)),
                amount = amount,
                item_list = itemList
            });

            this.payment = new Payment()
            {
                intent = "sale",
                payer = payer,
                transactions = transactionList,
                redirect_urls = redirUrls
            };
            // Create a payment using a APIContext
            return this.payment.Create(apiContext);
        }
    }
}
```

**Los parámetros que quiero envíar son el precio y la descripción al método "PaymentWithPayPal".**

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con AJAX y jQuery.

Por ejemplo, al hacer `click` a un botón determinado, realizas una llamada AJAX a la Acción del controlador con los parámetros `price` y `product`.

```
  $(function () {
      $('#id-boton').click(function () {
      e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("PaymentWithPaypal", "PayPal")", // Url
                data: {
                    price: $("#id-price").val(), // Parámetros
                    product: $("#id-product").val()
                },
                type: "post"  // Verbo HTTP
            })
            // Se ejecuta si todo fue bien.
            .done(function (result) {
                if (result != null) {
                }
                else {
                }
            })
            // Se ejecuta si se produjo un error.
            .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {

            })
            // Hacer algo siempre, haya sido exitosa o no.
            .always(function () {

            });
      });
  });
```

Comment: ¿Y esto debería ir en la vista o en el js?

Comment: Eso es código JavaScript jQuery, debe de ir en la Vista dentro de un script `<script />`. No conoces jQuery?

Comment: No, no conozco mucho, estoy empezando como estudiante

Comment: Pues empiezas fuerte amigo! .. haciendo de entrada un monedero PayPal en ASP.NET MVC con AJAX, sin saber jQuery ni JS...

Comment: Pues si amigo, mi universidad se caracteriza por eso jaja empezar fuerte. Pregunta ¿cómo obtiene el jQuery los valores del formulario? Debo incluir lo que tengo dentro del método update en el.done?